# AngularJS forms: display validation errors on submit?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I am using Angular JS 1.5.11.

I have a form with error messages and styling on my fields.  I have found information on how to trigger the validation on blur, debounce, etc.

But I *also* want the fields to be checked when the form is submitted.  I have found info on how to tell if the form is valid on submit and then process the form -- just not how to active the field error messages when the user submits.

To clarify:  I have error message on my fields.  When the user submits, if there are errors on field(s) I want the error messages to appear (and the user must fix the errors and re-submit).

I have something like this:

```
 <form name="abc.myForm" class="spacer-top-md" ng-submit="abc.save(abc.user)" novalidate>

 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : myForm.name.$invalid && !myForm.name.$pristine }">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="abc.user.name" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur'}" required>
  <p ng-show="myForm.name.$invalid && !myForm.name.$pristine" class="help-block">Enter your name.</p>
</div>

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
```

And in my controller:

```
  _this.master = {};

  _this.save = function (user) {
    _this.master = angular.copy(user);
  };

  _this.reset = function () {
    _this.user = angular.copy(_this.master);
  };

  _this.reset();
```

The submit works, the data is copied from the `user` object to the `master` object.  But if there are empty fields, no errors.  The only way to trigger errors so far is to enter data into the fields and tab out.

Comment: probably update required for `ng-required="true"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
   myForm.$submitted && myForm.email.$error.required
```

OR, alternatively:

```
 <form name="form" ng-app>
 <div class="control-group" ng-class="{true: 'error'}[submitted &&      form.email.$invalid]">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Your email address</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required />
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.required">Required</span>
        <span class="help-inline" ng-show="submitted && form.email.$error.email">Invalid email</span>
    </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large" ng-click="submitted=true">Submit</button>
```

Comment: note that since I am using the "controller as" format, your first tip needs to be `abc.myForm.$submitted && abc.myForm.name.$error.required`

Answer (score 0):

You should include ng-messages directive to your app,

here is snippet what you should add to your html, to use ng-messages directive.

'required' attribute in input element will be watched by directive and triger messages.

Don't forget for dependency injection in module.

```html
<div ng-messages="abc.myForm.name.$error" ng-show="abc.myForm.name.$touched">
                <p ng-message="required">This field is required.</p>
            </div>
```